# Sencha Touch: How to determine an input is the last in a FieldSet

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

So, if you add a bunch of inputs to a FieldSet, the last one has round corners on the bottom. In my form, tho, I hide and show inputs inside the form, depending on a Checkbox at the top of the form.

So now, it is possible that an input, tho logically not the last one in the Fieldset, to be visually, and temporarily, the last one.

Does anybody know how Sencha determines which is the last input in the Fieldset? Just looks which one is the last in the array of inputs, or there is a property I can set to an input to tell it that it is the last one now ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CSS rule, .x-form-fieldset .x-field:last-child, which styles the last child of a fieldset to have rounded bottom corners.  There is a bit more to the rule to handle edge cases, but any fields that are added (or hidden/shown) to that fieldset will have the appropriate styling applied just based on their HTML position alone.

The appropriate rule is in \resources\themes\stylesheets\sencha-touch\default\widgets\_form.scss:294 in release 1.1.0.

Comment: I've gave you the credit because you've forced me to rethink an option that sprung mu mind, and I thank you for that. Bellow, is what I actually did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [mistagrooves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605638/mistagrooves) post [from above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662638/sencha-touch-how-to-determine-an-input-is-the-last-in-a-fieldset/5668057#5668057), I've managed to fix the problem. The idea is that I programmaticlly set a class "last" to the input I want it t be rendered as last, and then in my CSS, I rewrite the rules for that .last class like so:

```
.last, .last .x-form-field-container, .last .x-form-field-container * 
{
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: .4em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .4em;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.last, .last .x-form-label, .last .x-form-label * 
{
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: .4em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .4em;
}
```

Hope it helps